# new project uses storyboard from old project

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I am creating a new Xcode project from scratch. But when I run the project I **always** see the view controller/scene from another project (by the same name). Even though the storyboard (ipad storyboard for now, but I have not made an iphone version) looks like a new scene, when I run the app on the simulator, I see the scene from an old app.

I am not copying over old files. Instead I have (re)created a test ipad storyboard from scratch and have only copied text from the most basic files over to the new files. The only files I have in the new project are `AppDelegate.h/m` and `ViewController.h/m` other than `MainStoryBoard_iPhone.storyboard` and `MainStoryBoard_iPad.storyboard`.

The problem is related to the fact that there is an old project by the same name. I have decided that this name is the one I want. Can I name a new project by a different name and then rename it after this problem is fixed? Or what can I do, short of erasing all the files that I have already created (because they have good stuff in them).

This `application:` method is slightly complicated, so I am copying it, just in case there is an issue related to it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        BDViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.viewController = (id)vc;
    } else {
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
        BDViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.viewController = (id)vc;
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the bundle identifier. The application temple auto generates it from the app name but you can change it in the Info.plist.

If this is a new app and the old own exists in the Store you can not use the same bundle id or app name.

If this is a new version of an old app that has never been published to the store then just reset the simulator (Menu "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Contents and Settings").

If this is a new version that has been published you need to update the version number.